# Obtaining GAMM intervals

Tags: r, correlation, gam, mgcv

I'm using a GAMM and want to extract the intervals for the model with the Variance-Covariance Matrix but am having problems doing so

Coding:

```
fishdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/4w0utkqdhqribl4/fishdata.csv", 
header=T)
attach(fishdata)
require(mgcv)

gammdl <- gamm(inlandfao ~ s(marinefao), correlation = corAR1(form = ~1 | year), 
family=poisson())

summary(gammdl$gam)
intervals(gammdl$lme)
```

but the final line of coding returns,

`Error in intervals.lme(gammdl$lme) : 
  cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components: Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance`

I don't see why this error message appears.

I'm trying to replicate what Simon Wood does on page 316 of *Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R* using my data.

Comment: You really *shouldn't* use `attach()` (for this at least). Delete that line and add `data = fishdata` to your `gamm()` call - when you fix the elephant in the room that I refer to in my answer below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Statistics (sorry- I don't seem to be able to recommend migration to stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You need to flag it separately and manually suggest it be migrate to [stats.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really an issue of statistical computation, not R usage. Essentially, the error means that whilst the computations might have converged to a fitted model, there are problems with that model. What this boils down to is that the Hessian computed at the fitted values of the model is non-positive definite, and hence the maximum likelihood estimate of the covariance matrix is not available. Often this occurs where the log-likelihood function becomes flat, no further progress in optimisation can occur, and arises from the fact that the model is most likely too complex for the given data.

You could try fitting the model with and without the AR(1) and compare them using a generalised likelihood ratio test (via `anova()`). I would guess that the AR(1) nested within `year` is redundant - i.e. the parameter $\phi$ is effectively 0 - and it is this that is causing the error.

<strike>Actually, now it also occurs to me that you are trying to model the variable `inlandfao` as a smooth function of itself `s(inlandfao)`. There is something wrong here - you'd expect a perfect fit without needing a smooth function. You need to fix that; you can't model the response as a function of itself.</strike>

Comment: Silly me, I've changed the predictor to `marinefao` but I'm still having the same issues.

Comment: @hgeop Then as I said, your model is too complex. Do you need the AR(1)?

Comment: OK perhaps my question is wrong then. I know there's some autocorrelation with the normal gam model `plot(acf(gammdl$gam$res))` so I need to take into account of this. Amending the GAMM model so that I only have `correlation = corAR1(form = ~1)` in the `gamm` argument allows me to obtain the intervals however the plot for the `gam` part of the model gives me a straight line `plot(updatedgamm$gam)` when using the `poisson()` family, which seems quite uninteresting and tells me that actually there isn't a nonlinear relationship?

Comment: Welcome to one of the problems of GAM modelling time series. The issue is that autocorrelation is not separable from the smooth term. You could treat the autocorrelation (AC) as a very wiggly smooth function in the model & no residual AC, or the converse, which is a linear smooth in the model and a high degree of AC in the AR(1). One option is make a guess at the degree of smoothness required for the `s()` term - how wiggly do you expect. State as as the `k` argument and use `fx = TRUE`. That way mgcv will estimate a smooth with that many dfs & the AR(1) can adapt to that.

Comment: @hgeop FYI, you want `plot(acf(resid(gammdl$gam, type = "normalized")))`. Don't extract components from model fits directly - the residuals you were using were working residuals, and you generally don't want/need them. Also, when you have the AR(1) in place, you need normalised residuals otherwise you'll end up pulling your hair out because the residual autocorrelation will still be present in the standard residuals...